# Minimizing $\mathbb E((X-m)^2)$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real random variable such that $X^2$ is integrable. I have to find $m$ minimizing $\mathbb E((X-m)^2)$.

How I *want* to do this is by saying:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E((X-m)^2) &= \int_\Omega (X-m)^2d\mathbb P \\
                   &= \int_\Omega X^2-2Xm+m^2d\mathbb P \\
                   &= \int_\Omega X^2d\mathbb P - 2m\int_\Omega Xd\mathbb P + \int_\Omega m^2d\mathbb P \\
                   &= \mathbb E(X^2) - 2m\mathbb E(X) + m^2
\end{align}
$$

Which is easy to minimize, yielding $m=\mathbb E(X)$. But aren't I assuming that $X$ is integrable? How do I justify this calculation given that I only know $X^2$ is integrable?

Comment: For $s<p$, if $\mathbb{E}(X^p)$ exists, then so does $\mathbb{E}(X^s)$.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Do you have a reference for a proof?

Comment: Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

More simply without invoking the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$|x| \leq 1+x^2\ \ \forall\, x \in \mathbb R \Rightarrow E[|X|] \leq 1 + E[X^2] < \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

As $$
E[|X|] = E[|X|\times 1] \le \sqrt{E[|X|^2]}\sqrt{E[1^2]} = \sqrt{E[X^2]}
$$if $E[X^2]<\infty$ then $E[|X|]<\infty$ too (this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality).